# Copying a Child Node into its Parent's Sibling's Child Node

Tags: xml, xslt

I've just started learning to use XLS for XML to XML transformations, so maybe this is a novice thing, but just can't seem to get the transformation I want in a single XSLT iteration, and am unable to find anything on this particular matter.
Here's what I've got:

**Source XML:**

```
<data>
<a/>
<b>
  <b1>ID#1</b1>
  <b2>
    <b2_1/>
  </b2>
</b>
<c>
  <b1>ID#1</b1>
  <b2_2/>
</c>
<!-- b and c nodes keep repeating with the same structure for different b1 IDs -->
</data>
```

What I need to do is to move `<b2_2>` node with its content from a `<c>` node to the  child node of the *specific* `<b>` node - with the value of `b/b1` equal to the value of `c/b1`.
So, bacicly, to move a Child node to it's Cousin node if their parents share a particular element of same value.

**Desired result:**

```
<data>
<a/>
<b>
  <b1>ID#1</b1>
  <b2>
    <b2_1/>
    <b2_2/>
  </b2>
</b>
</data>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:variable name="id1" select="b1"  />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::c[b1=$id1]/b2_2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c"/>
```

This code does a part of the job - it moves the target `<b2_2>` node to the target `<b>` node, while cleaning the redundant `<c>` node.

**What I get now**:

```
<data>
<a/>
<b>
  <b1>ID#1</b1>
  <b2>
    <b2_1/>
  </b2>
  <b2_2/>
</b>
</data>
```

I can see how to make the desired transformation in two steps with two XSLT files, but I feel like the solution is simple and on the surface. Can't nail the way to put the target node to the subnode where it is supposed to be, so will appreciate any tips at the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../following-sibling::c[1]/b2_2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer to link by `b1` value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="c" match="c" use="b1" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('c', ../b1)/b2_2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a swift answer! You're right, I must link the nodes by `b1` value. Sorry for not clarifying it in the first place, but `b2` has already other elements than `b2_2`, and your code clears them in the process. I edited the question so that this point is clearer.

Comment: Easy fix - see above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael, your answer turned me in the right direction and after studying the rules of `xsl:key` use I successfully implemented your offered solution to the actual data.